# Migrating a PostgreSQL database to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench, iso-8859-1, cp1252

I realize that this looks like a duplicate at first glance, but hear me out -

I'm trying to use MySQL Workbench to copy data from a remote PostgreSQL server to my MySQL server. I'm having problems with the character set for some reason. The schema in my PostgreSQL instance is using the default character set (cp1252 aka English_UnitedStates.1252). When I try migrating that database to my MySQL server using the character set latin1 (which is apparently the same as cp1252), I get all kinds of data errors, such as this one

```
    12:03:09 [INF][      copytable]: Statement execution failed: Incorrect string value: '\xE9volte...' for column 'user' at row 35:
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: *"The schema in my PostgreSQL instance is using the default character set..."* You can set the default character encoding when you install PostgreSQL, and you can override that when you create a database. Examine the output of this query: `select * from pg_database;`. What character encoding do you see for your database? (cp1252 isn't one of the possibilities.) What version of PostgreSQL? What version of MySQL? What version of MySQL Workbench?